# How to send email with edit URL from a google form?

Tags: google-sheets

I already have the script ready to add Edit Url to a column on the spreadsheet with the header 'Edit Url'. Now, how do I send an email to the participant that has the value in the 'Edit Url' column as part of the message body.

Here's the script to get the Edit Url and add it to the spreadsheet:

```
/*
 * Global Variables
 */`enter code here`

// Form URL
var formURL = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1dLhH9GVu9mLNy7JdikXGvNwSjgl-3GJDG98kxyDOxhM/viewform';
// Sheet name used as destination of the form responses
var sheetName = 'Form Responses 1';
/*
 * Name of the column to be used to hold the response edit URLs 
 * It should match exactly the header of the related column, 
 * otherwise it will do nothing.
 */
var columnName = 'Edit Url' ;
// Responses starting row
var startRow = 2;

function getEditResponseUrls(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues(); 
  var columnIndex = headers[0].indexOf(columnName);
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var form = FormApp.openByUrl(formURL);
  for(var i = startRow-1; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i][0] != '' && data[i][columnIndex] == '') {
      var timestamp = data[i][0];
      var formSubmitted = form.getResponses(timestamp);
      if(formSubmitted.length < 1) continue;
      var editResponseUrl = formSubmitted[0].getEditResponseUrl();
      sheet.getRange(i+1, columnIndex+1).setValue(editResponseUrl);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I email the user the edit URL with this code added to the script on the form

// Email edit response URL
    var editURL = e.response.getEditResponseUrl();

```
MailApp.sendEmail(Email, subject,
```

"\n\nYou can edit your responses at: " + editURL +
 "\n\nYou can submit a new report at: http://google-form.com" +